# ant clean issue with special character

Tags: ant

If I run ant clean for

```
<target name="clean">
      <delete file="Project.jar"/>
     </target>
```

It deletes the jar file

if I use

```
<target name="clean">
   <delete file="*.jar"/>
 </target>
```

it doesn't delete the any .jar that is in the directory.

Can someone please let me know what am I missing?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<delete>
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/somedirectory" includes="*.jar"/>
</delete>
```

This will delete all .jar files in some directory. We can't see the special character you have anywhere in the code you provided though, so I am not sure if this is what you need...?

Comment: No problem, I hope that did what you wanted it to :)